# jQuery dragging <div> outside the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

So I am testing with jQuery UI's `dragging()`. It makes dragging simple, but I realized a problem when playing with it.

```
$("#drag").draggable();​
```

```
<div id="drag"></div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/NS9s4/

While I am are dragging it, the `<div>` will stop as I moved out the window. I do not want this behavior. Is there any way that can make it still draggable outside the window? I know it is possible because I have seen it in many pages of Google services, but it is that I don't know how they did it.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you test this outside of jsfiddle? 
Also keep in mind that if they let go outside of the window you'll want to make sure you have the object appear in a visible location :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this demo they provide:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/default.html

It seems to do what you're looking for? Are you using the current version?

I also noticed that on their website they had the following css for the demo:

```
overflow: auto;
```